# HTTPS (letsencrypt) squid proxy on a domain?

Tags: proxy, https, squid, http-proxy

I'd like to make a HTTPS squid proxy ([this kind](https://superuser.com/questions/1196170/what-does-it-mean-for-proxy-server-to-be-of-https-type)) that can be used by anyone to access any site. This is not a reverse proxy, it is for the whole internet. For security reasons, IPs on my subnet should not be allowed to be accessed. I got a LetsEncrypt certificate for `proxy.mydomain.com` and I am wondering how to configure squid correctly for this. Here is my current config file:

```
########### squid.conf ###########
#
## interface, port and proxy type
#http_port 0.0.0.0:80 transparent
https_port 0.0.0.0:443 intercept tls-cert="/etc/letsencrypt/live/proxy.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem"

## timeouts
forward_timeout 30 seconds
connect_timeout 30 seconds
read_timeout 30 seconds
request_timeout 30 seconds
persistent_request_timeout 1 minute
client_lifetime 20 hours

## host definitions
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8

acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

http_access deny localnet

## proxy server client access
acl mynetworks src 127.0.0.0/8 10.10.10.0/28
#http_access deny !mynetworks

## max connections per ip
acl maxuserconn src 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.10.0/28
acl limitusercon maxconn 500
http_access deny maxuserconn limitusercon

## disable caching
cache deny all
cache_dir null /tmp

## disable multicast icp
icp_port 0
icp_access deny all

## disable ident lookups
ident_lookup_access deny all

## no-trust for on-the-fly Content-Encoding
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache

## logs
logformat combined [%tl] %>A %{Host}>h "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log combined
cache_store_log /var/log/squid/store.log
cache_log  /var/log/squid/cache.log
logfile_rotate 8

## support files
coredump_dir /tmp
pid_filename /var/log/squid/squid.pid

## ports allowed
acl Safe_ports port 80 443
http_access deny !Safe_ports

## ssl ports/method allowed
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

## protocols allowed
acl Safe_proto proto HTTP SSL
http_access deny !Safe_proto

## methods allowed
acl Safe_method method CONNECT GET HEAD POST OPTIONS PUT PATCH
http_access deny !Safe_method

## allow replies to client requests
http_reply_access allow all

##########  END  ###########
```

I edited `/etc/init.d/squid` to run squid with the flag `--with-openssl`.

Running `sudo service squid status` results in everything looking fine.

Yet when I try to connect to that proxy via `curl -p https://localhost:443 api.ipify.org -v`, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I don't have any firewalls running, and `lsof -i:443` has empty output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to configure an SSL cert within squid in order to run an HTTPS proxy.

If you look at the [Accepted Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1196205) on the question you linked to, you should understand why.

For an HTTPS proxy, the connection from your browser to the proxy (`proxy.mydomain.com`) is not secure, but the first thing the browser does with your proxy is issue the `CONNECT` command to the proxy to initiate a connection to the HTTPS destination.

So it's HTTPS from your browser to superuser.com and `proxy.mydomain.com` is just shuffling data, unable to read any of it.